# Connection refused (max retries exceeded) after only a few requests

Tags: python, connection

My script does a pretty simple scrape, accessing www.songfacts.com:

```
  url = getSongUrlFor(title)
  page = requests.get(url).text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser').get_text()
```

It seems to work fine when I only run the first two lines but once I add the BeautifulSoup call, the connection is blocked:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: 
HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.songfacts.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded         
with url: /search-songs-1.php?bohemian+rhapsody (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x1038bb6d0>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))
```

I've accessed the page using `requests` several times with no problem, but the very first time using `BeautifulSoup` stops not only python (even going back to just `requests`) but also Chrome and Safari from accessing this particular website for some undefined amount of time (currently it's about an hour later and I still can't get to it).

The next morning I can access the site again, until I try `BeautifulSoup` and then it breaks it.

Strangely, this problem doesn't reproduce with other websites I've tried.

Help.

Update: Switching IP addresses (now tethering from my iPhone) it worked once or twice (w/o BeautifulSoup) but then:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Comment: You can try selenium too. But they might be detecting beautiful soup and blocking your ip address.

Comment: @Morpheus How could the website detect BeautifulSoup? All it sees is the `requests.get()` call.

Comment: Is there perhaps a `try...except...pass` in the code that is running, that you haven't put in your question? I'm asking this because it can't be BeautifulSoup so it must be something else.

Comment: It seems that if you hit the site with a few hundred requests per minute it blocks your ip (can't access it via browser either). So you'll have to adjust your script not to exceed that limit.

Comment: That's a good point that it can't detect BeautifulSoup, it just seems like that's what's setting it off – I'm fairly sure that requests works fine until I introduce BS4. Even though that doesn't really make sense. Also, I'm not accessing the site very often. Maybe, I dunno, 10x per minute max; just when I make a change and need to test my program (or maybe slightly more than that, since I think the program accesses the site 3 times).

Comment: Add a 10s delay between requests. BS is not the problem.